# Gnirehtet VPN created, but there is no internet

Tags: android, tethering

I am trying to reverse tether across a USB cable. I have started the relay server and enable USB debugging on the tablet.

The connection has been successful and it looks like there are requests, but the tablet never receives anything back from the server.

This is an example log from the server:

```
2018-08-27 11:45:12.251 INFO Main: Checking gnirehtet client...
2018-08-27 11:45:12.250 INFO Main: Starting relay server...
2018-08-27 11:45:12.262 INFO Relay: Relay server started
2018-08-27 11:45:12.349 INFO Main: Starting client...
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.genymobile.gnirehtet.START 
cmp=com.genymobile.gnirehtet/.GnirehtetControlReceiver }
Broadcast completed: result=0
2018-08-27 11:45:16.061 INFO TunnelServer: Client #0 connected
2018-08-27 11:45:19.703 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:40346 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:29.715 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:28808 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:29.716 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:54996 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:37.700 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:54258 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:39.722 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:50461 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:39.723 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:55277 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:49.730 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:43497 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:49.730 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:39128 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:49.731 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:11340 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:59.740 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:10181 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:45:59.740 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:42187 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:46:09.749 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:47269 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:46:44.203 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:16753 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:46:54.213 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:24256 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:47:04.223 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:56571 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
2018-08-27 11:47:14.234 INFO UdpConnection: 10.0.0.2:28253 -> 8.8.8.8:53 
Open
```

When I try to access the web from the tablet everything just times out. Could this be a firewall issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access 8.8.8.8 (a Google DNS server) from your computer? If it's blocked, that's the cause of the issue.

You can specify your custom DNS server as follow (replace `xx.xx.xx.xx`):

```
./gnirehtet run -d xx.xx.xx.xx
```